# Is there a spatially constrained Raster Calculator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, field-calculator

This is a slightly random question, and difficult to find relevant material online. I'm curious if there is a way to use the Raster Calculator functionality on only the section of a raster covered by a polygon.

I'd like to use this to update sections within my raster with certain formula, but not the entire surface as the raster calculator would normally act.

I did find the 'Serval' plugin, which seems to be a step in the right direction, but still doesn't quite do what I'm looking for.

Comment: What about processing toolbox? First Clip raster by mask layer and Raster calculus of SAGA or GRASS r.mapcalc. You can create model or create python script to make the process repeatable.

Comment: hi @zoltan, thanks for your suggestions. That would work, but would create a separate raster file that would need to be overlaid on the original. Any ideas of how to 'overwrite' the values in the original raster with the new values?

Answer (score 2):

I think the term is 'masking'.

You could try an approach like this:-

- use gdal_rasterize to create a "mask" image (0=outside polygon, 1=inside polygon)
- apply your filter to your "original" raster to get a "processed" raster
- use the following function in QGIS raster calculator to blend the results

  (("mask@1"=0) * "original@1") + (("mask@1"=1) * "processed@1")

This works on the assumption that "false" is 0 and "true" is 1 - which seems to be the case on all the raster calculators I've tried (some allow if / else, some don't). You could also apply a similar formula with `r.mapcalc`, `gdal_calc` or `SAGA Grid Calculus/Raster Calculator`, but you will need to change the syntax.

GRASS also has a facility to produce masks, see [r.mask](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.mask.html). That looks promising - especially if you **don't** want your analysis to consider cells outside of the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS itself often uses other libraries to manipulate data, and usually create new files.

If you want to update a file, I would not use raster calculator but I would use the gdal_rasterize function. However, it can only "burn" a value (which seems ok in your case) but is not able to do complex math.

> gdal_rasterize -burn value_to_burn -l your_shapefile your_shapefile.shp your_raster.tif

Here above I burn the "value_to_burn" on "your_raster.tif" where the polygon exists. The raster must support update mode access, of course. If you want something slightly more complex, you can use a field values (with -a) or you can use a SQL clause based on some values of your raster band. If you have several bands, you can use the -b option.

Be careful, there is no way back after burning.